# Выражение "рассмотреть сложившуюся ситуацию"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить: «Прошу рассмотреть сложившуюся ситуацию»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Сочетание ***рассмотреть ситуацию*** используется, причем в текстах разного стиля:

Отдельно следует **рассмотреть ситуацию**, когда в процессе работы над задачей принято решение ввести дополнительный элемент. [А. И. Гасанов и др. Учебник по ТРИЗ (2000)]

Уныние ― смертный грех. Попробуем рассмотреть ситуацию еще раз. Вдруг что-то и нарисуется. [Ирина Павская. «Джоконда» Мценского уезда (2006)]

Для того чтобы понять это, надо хотя бы кратко **рассмотреть ситуацию**, сложившуюся вокруг ЕМК. [Дмитрий Фролов. Исключения из правил (2004) // «Бизнес-журнал», 2004.02.13]

Если это просьба разобраться в каком-то деле, то текст может быть оформлен следующими образом: **Прошу рассмотреть сложившуюся ситуацию и дать рекомендации к дальнейшим действиям/принять меры/помочь и т.д.**

Answer (score 0):

Вполне нормальная канцелярская фраза. Что именно вызвало у вас сомнения?

Comment: Ответ заканчивается вопросом. Почему не аргументом?

Comment: @shampar потому что, как кажется, он здесь не слишком нужен. Постараюсь позже добавить его, раз вы считаете это необходимым.

Comment: просто вся эта канцелярщина режет мой нежный слух

Comment: @Константин в канцелярском мире без нее никак

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически фраза вполне корректна. Но тут хотелось бы видеть контекст, возможно что в какой-то конкретной ситуации она просто не совсем уместна по смыслу.

Присоединяюсь к вопросу о том, что именно вам в ней не понравилось.